# can't build with Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic2 application and now I want to make a build but I get an error.

`ionic info` returns this:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v4.2.6
```

my **main.prod.ts** looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Everytime I try to do `ionic build android` I get this:

```
 bundle failed: Could not resolve './app.module.ngfactory' from /home/xxx/Desktop/myApp/.tmp/app/main.prod.ts 
ionic-app-script task: "build"
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic2 uses the Ahead-Of-Time-Compilation of Angular2 (by using `ngc`). What `ngc` does, is creating a factory out of your normal app-module and renames this module by adding `NgFactory` to the modules' Name.

So for example if you have an app-module called `MySuperAwesomeApp`, `ngc` creates a file which exports a factory called `MySuperAwesomeAppNgFactory`. And when building your Android app, ionic will search for `MySuperAwesomeAppNgFactory` instead of `MySuperAwesomeApp`, thus throwing an error, when not finding it.

In your case I suppose that you renamed your app-module (located in `./app.module.ts`) but didn't change the factory name in the **main.prod.ts**.

For further reading on AOT, please refer to the [Angular2 AOT Doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).